# Convert and apk file to binary using python

Tags: python-3.x, apk

I'm trying to convert an apk file into binary. I used the open(), and certain apk parsers but couldn't get the output I want.

Do you happen to know any methods/libraries that I could use in python?

When i use open(), using ("rb") option, a sort of shell code gets output. this is confusing me

I used apk_parse_ph4 too, only to realize later that it doesn't work for python3.4 :/

tried apktool too but only got the apk file unzipped..

```
apk_file = open("E:/test.apk", "rb")
print (apk_file.read())
print(type(apk_file))
```

The expected outcome is to have the apk file as 0110111110000

I'm a newcomer to this language and have been struggling on this for weeks.

A thanks in advance to anyone to spends some time on this since you will be helping me on my thesis.